# How to become Oracle dba expert?

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I'm an aspiring Oracle DBA. I want to improve my dba skills asap.Is there any website or ebook 
which will have step by step information to guide me through practicing DBA task at home.

Hoping for a favorable reponse!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is one website for this - [the ultimate, the best, the one and only you'll ever need](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/index.htm). And the [eBook you are looking for](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/toc.htm) is also there.

And definitely give [this introduction manual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodidacticism) a try.